# Magento 2.3 PHP Parse error unexpected '?' in write.php

Tags: error, cron, magento2.3, ssh, php-7.2

I want to Install cron with putty SSH. I use `php bin/magento cron:install [--force]` and get this error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable
>   (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /www/htdocs/xxx/xxx/xxx/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php
>   on line 35

Server run with **PHP** Version **7.2.11-nmm1**. What can I do? Where I can begin to search for it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your php version does not parse correctly **Nullable types** (such as that `?PathValidatorInterface`), which were introduced in php7.1 http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\WriteFactory $fileFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverInterface $driver,
    $path,
    $createPermissions = null,
    ?PathValidatorInterface $pathValidator = null
) {
    parent::__construct($fileFactory, $driver, $path, $pathValidator);
    if (null !== $createPermissions) {
        $this->permissions = $createPermissions;
    }
}
```

Double check your php version in command line, as it does not seem to be 7.2

It is not rare to have more than 1 php version installed, for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/50591861/1073040

Comment: Yes I checked: PHPinfo.php detect: the 7.2 Version and if I check with: "php -version in SSH i get the info : 7.0.32. Where I can change the version to 7.2?

Comment: You'd uninstall or disable 7.0... the way to do that would depend by the operative system you use. If you are in a Unix server & using Apache as webserver I have referenced an example for it